# Array refill after initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Probably something minor someone can just correct in under a minute.

But basically I'm trying to reset the values in an array if the type of object is different from the default type "1".  Getting errors atm, about initializer-list cannot be used

```
   GLfloat foodAmbient[] = { 0.3f, 0.6f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat foodSpecular[] = { 0.3f, 0.6f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat foodDiffuse[] = { 5.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    GLfloat foodShininess[] = { 50.0 };

    if (type == 2)
    {
        foodDiffuse = { 0.3f, 0.3f, 5.3f, 1.0f };
    }

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, foodAmbient);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, foodSpecular);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, foodDiffuse);
```

Comment: Raw arrays don't support assignment. But you can use e.g. `std::copy` to copy the data in. Better, you can use `std::array` and then you can assign.

Answer (score 1):

```
foodDiffuse = { 0.3f, 0.3f, 5.3f, 1.0f };
```

is wrong because you cannot assign to an array like that. That syntax can be used only to initialize an array. After an array is initialized, you can only change the individual elements of the array.

Replace that line with:

```
foodDiffuse[0] = 0.3f;
foodDiffuse[1] = 0.3f;
foodDiffuse[2] = 5.3f;
foodDiffuse[3] = 1.0f;
```